# having trouble registering collision

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics

I've been having trouble with getting my bullet (named asteroid) and my zombie. more specifically, I'm having trouble getting my game to register collision between these two turtles, it gets even weirder when you reverse the lesser than symbol into a greater than symbol. I do not know what is up with my code, any help is appreciated.(I have included the entirety of my code, since I am unsure of the source of the problem, I just know which part isn't working, I would recommend starting there.)

```
#the bullet that doesn't hit it's target

#Turtle Graphics game 
import turtle
import random
import time

#set up screen 
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("grey")

finish= False

def randor1():
    rand=random.randint(-280,280)

def randor2():
    rand=random.randint(50,280)

 def check_target_pos():
   #side boundary checking 
    if zombie.xcor() > 280 or zombie.xcor() <- 280:
        zombie.right(180)

    #top/bottom boundary checking 
    if zombie.ycor() > 280 or zombie.ycor() <- 280:
        zombie.right(180)

 def check_turtle_pos():
  #side boundary checking 
    if asteroid.xcor() > 280 or asteroid.xcor() <- 280:
        asteroid.right(180)

   #top/bottom boundary checking 
    if asteroid.ycor() > 280 or asteroid.ycor() <- 280:
        asteroid.right(180)

def new_asteroid():# the turtle bullet,will change the name later on
    for i in range(50):
        asteroid.forward(10)
    asteroid.goto(0,0)


def k2():#turn turtle left
    asteroid.left(45)


def k3():#turn turtle right
    asteroid.right(45)


#Draw border for arena
mypen = turtle.Turtle()
mypen.penup()
mypen.setposition(-300,-300)
mypen.pendown()
mypen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    mypen.forward(600)
    mypen.left(90)
    mypen.hideturtle()


#create turtle turtle, again will change name later
asteroid = turtle.Turtle()
asteroid.color("green")
asteroid.shape("turtle")
asteroid.penup()
asteroid.speed(0)


 #create turtle zombie
def zombies():
    global zombie
    zombie= turtle.Turtle()
    zombie.hideturtle()
    zombie.color("green")
    zombie.shape("circle")
    zombie.penup()
    zombie.speed(0)

    x= random.randint(-280,280)
    y= random.randint(50,280)

    zombie.goto(x,y)
    zombie.showturtle()

zombies()

while (finish!= True):
    check_target_pos()
    check_turtle_pos()

    zombie.forward(1)
    def end():
        finish==True
        wn.bye()
    if asteroid.distance(zombie)<40: #problem area
        end()    

    wn.onkey(new_asteroid, "space")#shoot button.
    wn.onkey(k2, "Left")#turn left button
    wn.onkey(k3, "Right") #turn right button
    wn.onkey(end, "e")#exit
    wn.listen()#so all the on key functions above work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is somewhat a mess and doesn't facilitate the event-driven nature of turtle.  There is no place for `while True:` loops nor `time.sleep()` or such in this environment.  You also seem to be confusing your gun with your bullet (you're flinging your gun into space to kill the zombie, not its bullet!)

I've rewritten your code below using an event-based model with `ontimer()`.  This is a *single bullet* implementation (you can't fire again until your bullet hits something or disappears into the distance):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def check_bullet_position():
    if bullet.distance(turtle) > 240:
        bullet.hideturtle()

    if bullet.distance(zombie) < 20:
        bullet.hideturtle()
        reset_zombie()

def shoot_bullet():
    if bullet.isvisible():
        return

    bullet.setheading(turtle.heading())
    bullet.setposition(turtle.position())
    bullet.forward(15)

    bullet.showturtle()

def turn_left():
    turtle.left(20)

def turn_right():
    turtle.right(20)

def reset_zombie():
    while zombie.distance(turtle) < 240:
        x = randint(-280, 280)
        y = randint(-280, 280)
        zombie.goto(x, y)

    zombie.setheading(zombie.towards(turtle))

def move():
    zombie.forward(1)

    if bullet.isvisible():
        bullet.forward(2)

    check_bullet_position()

    screen.update()

    if turtle.distance(zombie) > 20:
         screen.ontimer(move)

# Set up screen
screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)
screen.bgcolor('grey')

# Draw border for arena
pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.pensize(3)

pen.penup()
pen.setposition(-300, -300)
pen.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    pen.forward(600)
    pen.left(90)

# Create turtle turtle
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.color('green')
turtle.penup()

# Create turtle bullet
bullet = Turtle()
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.shape('circle')
bullet.shapesize(0.5)
bullet.color('yellow')
bullet.penup()

# Create turtle zombie
zombie = Turtle()
zombie.shape('circle')
zombie.color('red')
zombie.penup()

reset_zombie()

screen.onkey(shoot_bullet, 'space')
screen.onkey(turn_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(screen.bye, 'e')  # exit
screen.listen()  # enable onkey() functions above

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

This should give you a starting point for building the game you envision. It is possible to write a *multiple bullet* implementation, it just take a little more thought and design work.

Answer (score 0):

Your searching for a collision outside of the loop where you shot the projectile.
The easiest way to make your code work is to add the collision detection to the new_asteroid() function. But I don't think that's the right way.

Your technique is what is referred to as `blocking`. while you're projectile is moving, no other code is running. hence your collision detection is not working. change Line 38 to this.

```
def new_asteroid():# the turtle bullet,will change the name later on
    for i in range(50):
        asteroid.forward(10)
        if asteroid.distance(zombie) < 40:  # problem area
            end()
    asteroid.goto(0,0)
```

To create a non-blocking version of this function you would have to divide the `for` loop up to increments called by your main loop. so that your projectile moves once per iteration, instead of all at once.

Your program also crashes on exit. May I recommend re organizing your code into functions, then execution. it makes it much more readable. Happy gaming.